# How to display the number of active contracts on the last day of a given period un lookerstudio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table where each row represents a contract. Among other features, the table contains the contract's start date and end date. The end date column can be null if the contract is still active today. See an example below:

| id_contract | date_start | date_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-10 | 2023-02-09 |
| B | 2023-04-13 | null |
| C | 2023-05-07 | 2023-05-22 |

I want to display in a bar chart (the x-axis being the date) the number of active contracts on the last day of a given period. A contract is considered active on that day if

```
date_start <= last_day and (date_end > last_day or date_end is null)
```

I want to be able to change the time grain of the bar chart in looker studio interactively (ie display the chart at the week, month, or quarter level). If I choose the quaterly level for instance, the chart shall display the number of active contracts on the last day of each quarter.

One workaround would be to precompute the different aggregations upfront (by using a date spine for example) - but I would prefer a solution that can be genuinely implemented in lookerstudio - is this actually doable?